# How to append copies of elements to Python list?

Tags: python, copy

I have a Python code that looks like this:

```
import random
import copy

symbols = set('ABC')
values = dict.fromkeys(symbols, [])

for i in range(5):
  value = random.randint(1, 100)
  if value % 3 == 0:
    values['A'].append(copy.deepcopy(value))
  elif value % 3 == 1:
    values['B'].append(copy.deepcopy(value))
  else:
    values['C'].append(copy.deepcopy(value))

print(values)
> {'B': [19, 31, 73, 9, 9], 'A': [19, 31, 73, 9, 9], 'C': [19, 31, 73, 9, 9]}
```

What I had hope is that each property of the dictionary would have different list of elements, however the end result I get is that all of them have the same numbers (as seen above). Why is this happening although I'm copying the element using `deepcopy`? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your problem is not with ``value`` (which is immutable anyway), but with the default value in ``fromkeys``.

Comment: @MikeScotty Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` to achieve the result you want.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random

values = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(5):
  value = random.randint(1, 100)
  if value % 3 == 0:
    values['A'].append(value)
  elif value % 3 == 1:
    values['B'].append(value)
  else:
    values['C'].append(value)

print(values)
```

And you don't need to copy `value`

`defaultdict(list)` creates a new list whenever a key in the dictionary is accessed the first time - so you will have 3 distinct objects as values in the dictionary.